# Component library to create embedded Windows GUI like Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a component library (free or commercial) to do so ?

I don't want to develop a programmers editor so Visual Studio Shell won't fit I think, I just want the GUI Window system alone for example for drawing charts with panels on the left to configure the charts.

I'm beginner so I prefer something that is well documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use WeifenLuo DockPanel Suite ([link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/)) which provides a VS like window environment.  It's open source so we've been able to modify it to support a bunch of new features as well.

Comment: problem is I'm beginner and someone said "It's a bit hard to make it do what you want if you are not an expert on that area"

Comment: Well there's no way to become familiar with a library other than using it. I suggest trying it in a small application and use the examples to do things you'll need to do in your actual application.  I've found it has 95% of the features I've needed already implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There's Visual Studio Isolated Shell, and Visual Studio Integrated Shell: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb685612.aspx

Comment: I don't want to develop a programmers editor, I just want the GUI Window system alone.

Comment: You can build any type of multi-window application with the shell. I think there's a demo of something like a home automation system or similar in the SDK.